# How do I ignore HTML when filtering a jQuery data table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the [jQuery DataTables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/), and having a slight problem with the filtering feature in it.  If I have a table cell with content like `<a href='foo6'>Blah</a>`, and I filter for "6", that cell will show up, even though there is no "6" in "Blah".  What I'd like to do is have the DataTables plug-in ignore HTML when doing it's filtering.

I've tried scouring the DataTables site, and found conflicting, un-helpful leads.  One post suggested that I needed an `sType:'html'` option in the definition of my aaColumns, but I tried that and it didn't help ... plus a later post suggested that the current version of DataTables auto-detects the HTML sType.  I also found this code snippet:

```
// Make filtering ignore HTML (see http://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering)
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['html'] = function ( sData ) {
    var n = document.createElement('div');
    n.innerHTML = sData;
    if (n.textContent) {
        return n.textContent.replace(/\n/g," ");
    } else {
        return n.innerText.replace(/\n/g," ");
    }
};
```

which was supposed to fix things ... but it didn't.

So, my question is: does anyone out there know how to make DataTables ignore non-text (ie. HTML) content when filtering rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out I needed a custom `mRender` function on my column headers.  More importantly (since I had tried this at first without checking the "type" argument) you need to use the type argument provided to that function to make it only apply when filtering.

My end result looked something like this:

```
aaHeaders: [{
    mRender: function(data, type, full) {
        // If we're filtering, don't look at the HTML; only filter on the text
        return type == 'filter' ? $(data).text() : data
    }
}], //...
```

Comment: I could not get this solution to work. Did you do any other changes?

Comment: Not that I remember, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one :

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['html'] = function ( sData ) {
    return $("<div/>").html(sData).text();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried that and it didn't work.  I even added a debugger line inside it, to check if it was getting run, but it turned out the code wasn't even getting hit :-(

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade your datatable.js.. I have used 1.9.4 and got the same problem after upgrading to 1.10.9 the problem resolved..

Answer (score 0):

```
// To override basic search functionality of datatable
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
                        var tableId = settings['sTableId'];
                        var searchTerm = settings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch;
                        if ( 'tableId' == tableId){
//I added tableId condition as I have multiple table on same page..
                            if(data[0].indexOf(searchTerm) > -1 ||data[2].indexOf(searchTerm) > -1||data[3].indexOf(searchTerm) > -1||data[4].indexOf(searchTerm) > -1||data[5].indexOf(searchTerm) > -1 || data[6].indexOf(searchTerm) > -1){
                                return true;
                            }else{
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
            );
```

Comment: to accompany your code, you might as well give a written description